# Legend not displaying on Line or Bar chart - React-Chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am having some difficulties getting the legend to display on several of my graphs in my react dashboard.
I am using React-Chartjs-2 . The legends were working originally, then I tested turning legends off in the Chart.default properties and when I tried to turn it back on, they did not reappear.

My global Chart settings are as follows:

```
// React-Chartjs-2 Global Styling 
defaults.global.elements.point.radius = 1;
defaults.global.elements.line.tension = 0.1;
defaults.global.elements.point.hoverRadius = 10;
defaults.global.elements.point.hitRadius = 12;

// Font
defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12;
defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "#838383";

// Legend
defaults.global.legend.display = true;
defaults.global.legend.align = "start";
defaults.global.legend.position = "bottom";
defaults.global.legend.labels = {
  padding: 30,
  boxWidth: 15,
};
```

My local chart properties for my Line, Bar and Doughnut charts all follow a similar layout, being:

```
        <Line
          data={props.graph.data}
          height={300}
          options={{
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
              display: true,
            },
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                  display: false
                }
              }],
              yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                  drawBorder: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero:true,
                  // Include a kwh sign in the ticks
                  callback: function(value, index, values) {
                      return value + 'kWh';
                  }
                },
              }]
            }
          }}
        />
```

As you can see, Legends are turned on in both global and local settings.
Currently, only the doughnut chart is displaying it's legend. Toggling the display:true value only shifts the bottom of the Line/Bar chart up and down a small amount.

Anybody encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the defaults can't handle being passed an object, if you define the defaults for the legend label padding and boxWidth separately then it will render your legend.

Normal example but problem was the same as if you would use react wrapper:

```js
const defaults = Chart.defaults;

defaults.global.elements.point.radius = 1;
defaults.global.elements.line.tension = 0.1;
defaults.global.elements.point.hoverRadius = 10;
defaults.global.elements.point.hitRadius = 12;

// Font
defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12;
defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "#838383";

// Legend
defaults.global.legend.display = true;
defaults.global.legend.align = "start";
defaults.global.legend.position = "bottom";
defaults.global.legend.labels.padding = 30;
defaults.global.legend.labels.boxWidth = 15;

var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas { 
 background-color : #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Already answer has been given even though, I would like to give alternative solution without `defaults` namespace options.

We can achieve it with `plugins` namespace  in **reactjs**.

```
 <Line
      data={{
        labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Primary kVA",
            data: [6, 17, 12, 19, 10, 55, 5, 22, 3, 100, 200, 350],
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
          },
          {
            label: "Redundant kVA",
            data: [12, 23, 33, 55, 22, 300, 100, 200, 350],
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: "rgb(77, 255, 156)",
            borderColor: "rgb(77, 255, 156,0.73)",
          },
        ],
      }}
      options={{
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: "right",
            align: "start",
            labels: {
              usePointStyle: true,
            },
          },
        },
      }}
    />
```

Comment: This is incorrect tho, since op is using v2 and this is v3 syntax this wont work, also you will need to do this for every chart you make while if you put it in the defaults you configure it once and its done for all charts which makes it much more maintainable